# intel xdk app install replaces the previous apk

Tags: android, intel-xdk

Hi I'm experimenting with xdk and created few apk for from different projects, but whenever I install the apk on my mobile, it will install as an update and replaces the app though the app and project is different. How do I install the apk as a new app? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `App ID` for your projects, if your projects have same default `App ID` then it will replace the previous install

Click Projects -> Build Settings and change the `App ID`

The `App ID` usually has this format: `com.companyName.appName`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, changing the ID did the trick for building android apps, but did not solve the problem in App preview (second app replaces the first).
I got this answer on the HTML5 Dev forum from a Technical Consulting Engineer
Intel Corporation, HTML5 Dev Tools:

The XDK gets its information regarding the name of the app, etc. from the .xdk file inside the project directory. If you did not change that, it might be the source of the problem. There is also a unique GUID inside that file which is probably the same for both of your projects. I believe if you set that GUID to all zeroes (replace each number in it with a zero) the XDK will reassign a new one to the project.

Just guessing, not 100% clear on what happened, but give that a try.

Worst case you may have to remove both projects, delete the .xdk files from each, and "import" them into the XDK.

**EkG: !! Changing the GUID in the *.xdk file does work, but not if you set them both to zero's.
You have to make them different manually.**